# How can I pass pipeline variable to parameters file for blueprint assignment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blueprints

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps pipeline for deploying Azure Blueprint. There are some fields in the parameters file(JSON) which I want to be configurable. How can I pass these values as pipeline variables and use them in the parameters file?

I tried defining a pipeline variable and reference it in the parameter file like this "$(var-name)", but it didn't work. Is there a way to solve this?

Below is my pipeline definition, I'm using AzureBlueprint extension for creating and assigning blueprint:

```
steps:
- task: CreateBlueprint@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
    BlueprintName: $(blueprintName)
    BlueprintPath: '$(blueprintPath)'
    AlternateLocation: false
    PublishBlueprint: true

- task: AssignBlueprint@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
    AssignmentName: '$(blueprintName)-assignment'
    BlueprintName: $(blueprintName)
    ParametersFile: '$(blueprintPath)/assign.json'
    SubscriptionID: $(subscriptionId)
    Wait: true
    Timeout: 500
```

and my parameters file:

```
"parameters":{
         "organization" : {
            "value": "xxxx"
         },
         "active-directory-domain-services_ad-domain-admin-password" : {
            "reference": {
               "keyVault": {
                     "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxx"
               },
               "secretName": "xxxx"
            }
         },
         "jumpbox_jumpbox-local-admin-password" : {
            "reference": {
               "keyVault": {
                     "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxx"
               },
               "secretName": "xxxx"
            }
         },         
         "keyvault_ad-domain-admin-user-password" : {
            "value" : "xxxx"
         },
         "keyvault_deployment-user-object-id" : {
            "value" : "xxxx"
         },
         "keyvault_jumpbox-local-admin-user-password" : {
            "value" : "xxxx"
         }
      }
```

Comment: Can you show us your pipeline definition? What Task are you using for deploying the blueprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Tasks (`CreateBlueprint` and `AssignBlueprint`) you are using doesn't support overriding parameters, you have two options:

- Use the Azure CLI [`az blueprint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/blueprint?view=azure-cli-latest&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) command to directly create and assign blueprints.
- Change the parameters file bei either using [**JSON variable substitution**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#json-variable-substitution) or by using a small PowerShell script (see blow):

**Sample:**

```
$paramFile = Get-Content ./azuredeploy.parameters.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$paramFile.parameters.organization.value = "your-org-name" 
$paramFile | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content ./azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

Be aware that the Task you are using hasn't received an update within the last 17 months (here is the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/neilpeterson/azure-blueprints-pipeline-tasks)).

Answer (score 1):

[`AssignBlueprint@1`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nepeters.azure-blueprints) doesn't support natively this. However you can modify `assign.json` using [Json substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#json-variable-substitution)

It comes down to having Azure Pipeline variables with a name like a path to a leaf in the json file which you want to teplace.

Here is an example:

```
variables:
  Data.DebugMode: disabled
  Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString: 'Data Source=(prodDB)\MSDB;AttachDbFilename=prod.mdf;'
  Data.DBAccess.Users.0: Admin-3
  Data.FeatureFlags.Preview.1.NewWelcomeMessage: AllAccounts

# Update appsettings.json via FileTransform task.
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File transformation: appsettings.json'
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    targetFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
    fileType: json
```